# How to find out CUDA cores and information on command line for NVIDIA GPU

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, cuda

Simply put, I want to find out on the command line the CUDA compute capability as well as number and types of CUDA cores in NVIDIA my graphics card on Ubuntu 20.04.

Any suggestions? I tried `nvidia-smi -q` and looked at `nvidia-settings` - but no success / no details. Also I forgot to mention I tried locating the details via `/proc/driver/nvidia`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the `nvidia-settings` utilities installed, you can query the number of CUDA cores of your gpus by running `nvidia-settings -q CUDACores -t`. If that's not working, try `nvidia-settings -q :0/CUDACores`.

- **:0** is the gpu slot/ID: In this case 0 is refering to the first GPU.
- **CUDACores** is the property

If have the `cuda` & `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` installed, try running `deviceQuery`. It's located somewhere in `/usr/local/cuda-11/extras/demo_suite/deviceQuery`
Try running locate deviceQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There is `/proc/driver/nvidia` which looks promising:

```
sh@balrog:~$ tree /proc/driver/nvidia
/proc/driver/nvidia
├── capabilities
│   ├── gpu0
│   │   └── mig
│   └── mig
│       ├── config
│       └── monitor
├── gpus
│   └── 0000:01:00.0
│       ├── information
│       ├── power
│       └── registry
├── params
├── patches
│   └── README
├── registry
├── suspend
├── suspend_depth
├── version
└── warnings
    └── README
```

...but I couldn't find the number of GPUs there.

```
sh@balrog:~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/*/information
Model:       NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
IRQ:         34
GPU UUID:    GPU-4087ca95-8a80-05fd-85f9-f50a4849fe4e
Video BIOS:      86.07.42.00.77
Bus Type:    PCIe
DMA Size:    47 bits
DMA Mask:    0x7fffffffffff
Bus Location:    0000:01:00.0
Device Minor:    0
GPU Excluded:    No
```

In some related articles, people are pointed to `nvcc` which is part of the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package. You might give that a try.

See also
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cuda-binaries.1.html

Comment: Yes, I tried to identified it as well with `/proc/driver/nvidia` but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend Jiahui Chen's answer a bit... Create a script with these query lines to get the number of cores, compute capability and CUDA version, which may be helpful, for instance, when installing torch or tensorflow.

```
echo " "
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv
echo "Number of CUDA Cores: $(nvidia-settings -q CUDACores -t)"
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=compute_cap --format=csv
nvidia-smi -q |grep CUDA
echo " "
```

Change the attributes of the script to make it executable and run with sudo or as root